# Java Comparator for comparing instances of a generic class

Tags: java, generics

I have the following comparator class:

```
public class CustomTupleComparator implements Comparator<Tuple>
{
    public int compare(Tuple o1, Tuple o2)
    {
        int result = o1.getSecond().compareTo(o2.getSecond());

        return result != 0
               ? result
               : - o1.getFirst().compareTo(o2.getFirst());
    }
}
```

The Tuple class itself is generic with two type parameters:

```
public class Tuple<T1 extends Comparable, T2 extends Comparable>
{...}
```

Why am I getting unchecked call warnings about the `compareTo()` methods?

Comment: changing the comparator definition to:
`... implements Comparator<Tuple<? extends Comparable, ? extends Comparable>>` didn't help either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Why am I getting unchecked call warnings about the `compareTo()` methods?

Because you are using raw type `Tuple`, instead of parameterized type. To use a parameterized type `Tuple` however, you would need to make the `CustomTupleComparator` class generic itself:

```
public class CustomTupleComparator<T1 extends Comparable<? super T1>, 
                                   T2 extends Comparable<? super T2>> 
             implements Comparator<Tuple<T1, T2>>
{
    @Override
    public int compare(Tuple<T1, T2> o1, Tuple<T1, T2> o2)
    {
        int result = o1.getSecond().compareTo(o2.getSecond());

        return result != 0 ? result
                           : -o1.getFirst().compareTo(o2.getFirst());
    }
}
```

Also, you should change your `Tuple` class, to make the type parameters use generic `Comparable`, and not raw type:

```
public class Tuple<T1 extends Comparable<? super T1>, 
                   T2 extends Comparable<? super T2>> { }
```

Note: I've used `Comparable<? super T1>` instead of `Comparable<T1>` so as to make it work for subtypes too, where the super types are implementing `Comparable<SuperType>`.

Also, since `Comparable`s are consumers, as they consume types that they are comparing, we use `? super T1`.